# While applying qcut to a data series I am getting the below mentioned Index error

Tags: python, pandas

Hi can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

```
#How to bin a numeric series to 10 groups of equal size?

ser = pd.Series(np.random.random(20))
s=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
label=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th','6th','7th','8th','9th','10th']
k=pd.qcut(ser,q=s,labels=label)
```

> IndexError: index 76 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20

The solution provided has the list passed directly in the qcut method rather than defining them as a variable

Answer (score 0):

Which pandas version do you have? In 1.3.5 everything works fine:

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.random(10))
s=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
label=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th','6th','7th','8th','9th','10th']
k=pd.qcut(ser,q=s,labels=label)
```

Output:

```
0      6th
1      3rd
2      3rd
3      5th
4      1st
5      1st
6     10th
7      9th
8      2nd
9      5th
10     8th
dtype: category
Categories (10, object): ['1st' < '2nd' < '3rd' < '4th' ... '7th' < '8th' < '9th' < '10th']
```

Comment: Thanks!! upgraded pandas & now the issue is resolved